# Mysql Regex on where clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, json, regex

I need a regular expression which will give me only those records which match a pattern.Below is table structure

```
auto_id (Auto-increment)  | json_string (Text)
```

Sample records are:

```
auto_id | json_string 
--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1 | {"12":"1774","13":"V.","14":"2","16":"9","17":"39","18":"59","19":"88","20":"144","21":"236"}
      2 | {"12":"1774","13":"Y.","14":"2","16":"7","17":"39","18":"59","19":"88","20":"144","21":"236"}
      3 | {"12":"1774","13":"V.","14":"2","16":"9","17":"39","18":"59","19":"88","20":"144","21":"236"}
```

My Query is :

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_json 
WHERE json_data REGEXP '"14":"[1|2]"' 
AND json_data REGEXP '"16":["39|7"]' 
LIMIT 3;
```

This should return only record with id 2. And not 1 and 3 as `"16":"39'` or `"16":"7"` is not part of the `json_string`.

Does anybody have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed the REGEXP syntax for alternatives `(first|second)` and for symbol classes `[abcd]`. Your query should look like that:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_json 
 WHERE json_data REGEXP '"14":"(1|2)"' 
   AND json_data REGEXP '"16":"(39|7)"' 
 LIMIT 3;
```